# getvoicemessagecount api of telephony manger is not accessible

Tags: java, android

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.6_r2/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.java

In above link line no 623 shows that telephony manager has getvoicemessagecount api. But in my program when i try is is not available to access.
I checked on android website but there it does not show any such api. Is this api exist ?if yes the how to access?

I basically want to get count of voicemail.

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Returns the voice mail count. Return 0 if unavailable.
 * <p>
 * Requires Permission:
 *   {@link android.Manifest.permission#READ_PHONE_STATE READ_PHONE_STATE}
 * @hide
 */
public int getVoiceMessageCount() {
    try {
        return getITelephony().getVoiceMessageCount();
    } catch (RemoteException ex) {
        return 0;
    } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        // This could happen before phone restarts due to crashing
        return 0;
    }
}
```

see the tag `@hide` at documentation. Means it is a hidden API. but you can access it using `Reflection` API...

```
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    try {
        Method method = telephonyManager.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getVoiceMessageCount");
        method.setAccessible(true);
        Object object = method.invoke(telephonyManager);
        int voiceMessageCount = (Integer) object;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // handle Exception
    }
```

Comment: i have never used reflection ..can you please guide?

Comment: I have never used reflection api ...can you guide me on how to use it?

Comment: voiceMessageCount  ...this variable will contain count of voice message returned by hidden api?

Comment: I am getting exception as nosuchmethod on line                                 Method method = telephonyManager.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getVoiceMessageCount");

Comment: may be this method is added in advanced API. I have tested it in API level 16 and it's working fine...

Comment: I am also checking in api level 16 ...mentioned in my manifest file.

Comment: 02-12 18:11:39.416: W/System.err(31401): java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: getVoiceMessageCount []

Comment: I can't say what the issue with your code. sorry. but It's working fine for me...

Comment: I can see below lines on checking method name by writing line of code
 Method[] checkMethod = telephonyManager.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
  for(Method m : checkMethod)  
   {  
            // Found a method m  
   System.out.println("method name is "+m.getName());
   }  
302-12 18:15:07.296: I/System.out(879): method name is getITelephony
02-12 18:15:11.511: I/System.out(879): method name is getDefault

Comment: you can see even  getNetworkTypeName() method is not listed in list neither any constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Class class1;

TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) mContext.getSystemService(mContext.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

```
 try {

class1 = Class.forName(TelephonyManager.class.getName());
Method createBondMethod = class1.getMethod("getVoiceMessageCount");
Integer returnValue = (Integer) createBondMethod.invoke(manager);
System.out.println("return value is "+returnValue);

  }
```